# Primefaces - datatable inside panelgrid has invisible selected row

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have p:dialog, inside there is p:panelGrid, and one of column is p:dataTable. Datatable has selectionmode single. Problem is: dataTable loses all styling it defaulty had (it looks like pure unstyled html table). Also when i click row in dataTable, row is invisible, no data is shown. Also rowSelect functionally works, because data from selected row displays in input fields in another outputPanel correctly. Its just invisible

Comment: You will need to provide the code snippet that's failing. Try and remove everything else that's not essential to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Also you didn't mention your version of PrimeFaces.  Many fixes to PanelGrid and DataTable over the years make sure this isn't an already fixed issue by trying PF10.